# Retrieving a field from Java REST Mongodb server

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jetty

I am using the Java Jetty based REST server listed on MongoDB website(Mongoser).

I am trying to retrieve a  field based on the matching _id filed and I am using the following format , but I get all the records back , can you please let me know if my syntax is correct.

I want only "myfield" to be returned for the matching _id , but it returns all the fields for all the ids , can you please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
    http://localhost:8082/query?dbname=mydb&colname=mycollection&fields=myfield
-XPOST -d'{_id:"
    51be48146a57f03f58b4d5f3"}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please write the query that you are using.

Comment: This is the RESTful interface for the MongoDB server , I am not using a query for this.